# C# Class System.Data.SqlClient can not load file or assembly

Tags: c#

How do I use the SqlClient directive with .NET Standard 2.0?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Having great difficulty with Visual Studio at the minute, when I run my program I am greeted with the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Resulting in the application not running, the directive has been installed via NuGet and my class .csproj looks like:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The Form's framewwork is set to .NET framework 4.6.1...
I can not change the class framework to match, and I am not sure if this is causing the error?

The methods - that are causing the error - referenced from the Class:

```
//Connect to Database
    public void Connection()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create SqlConnection
            connString = "Data Source = xx; Initial Catalog = xx; User ID = xx; Password = xx";
            con = new SqlConnection(connString);
            con.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error;
            error = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1) You might have already tried this.
Remove the reference & add it manually.

Option 2) Somehow System.Data.SqlClient dll is missing from your output or build folder
So, try adding post build script.

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy ..\..\..\packages\System.Data.SqlClient\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Data.SqlClient.dll bin\Debug\appname\" Condition="'$(IsWindows)' == 'true'" />
    <Exec Command="cp ../../../packages/System.Data.SqlClient/runtimes/unix/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Data.SqlClient.dll bin/Debug/appname/" Condition="'$(IsWindows)' != 'true'" />
</Target>
```